# Use AJAX to insert into database without refreshing the page

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to write PHP code (req_form.php) which is supposed to insert into an SQL Database "Requests" without refreshing the page, by sending inserted data to (insert.php) and its just not working :(

Here is my **"Request" table**:
[Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8Yr1.jpg)

**req_form.php:**

```
<form action="req_form.php" method="post">
  <textarea id="des" name="des" placeholder="Problem description" type="text" required></textarea>
  <input id="date" name="date" placeholder="Date (YEAR-MONTH-DAY)" type="date"/>
  <input id="time" name="time" placeholder="Time (Hour:Minute)" type="time"/>
  <button type="submit" name="send" id="send" onclick="Send_req()"> Send</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
   function Send_req() {
     var des= $("#des").value;
     var time= $("#time").value;
     var date= $("#date").value;
     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'insert.php',
        data: {des:des, time:time, date:date;},
        success: function(html) 
        {
            if (html=='1')
            {
                alert ("Congratulations, Request Sent Successfuly! ");
            }

            else
            {
                alert ("Sorry, Error in sending request!");
            }
        }
    }); 
      }
</script>
```

**insert.php:**

```
<?php 
$connect= mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Can't connect to database!");
$db = mysql_select_db("hwp",$connect) or die ("Can't select database!");

if($_POST["des"] !="" && $_POST["date"] != "" && $_POST["time"] !="" )
{
    $des= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["des"]);
    $date= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["date"]);
    $time= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["time"]);
    $sender= '1';
    $receiver= '2';
    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO request (Req_sender_id, Req_receiver_id, Req_date, Req_time, Req_msg) VALUES ( '$sender','$receiver','$date','$time','$des');") or die(mysql_error());
      if  ($sql)  
    {
        echo '1';
    }

    else
    {
        echo '0';
    }
}
?>
```

What is the problem??!

Comment: For one thing, `<textarea>` does not have a "type", remove `type="text"` and make sure the jQuery library is loaded. check your console and errors.

Comment: Rather than just saying "its not working", how about explaining what isn't working and what you are seeing.

Comment: Try with `data: "des="+des+"&time="+time+"&date="+date,`

Comment: what is the version you're using in php !!

Comment: @devpro - that's not necessary. jQuery properly handles objects as the post data.

Comment: `$("#des").value` use like that `$("#des").val()` other aswell

Comment: There is no possible way to help here.  What "is not working"? Do you have any javascript errors? Are you watching your developers console? Google "How to troubleshoot AJAX problems", and (1) use the tools at your disposal to get information about what is happening, and (2) report back here with a *specific description of the problem*

Comment: @smerny u r right... :p

Comment: U also need to remove `action="req_form.php"` and need to use `return false;` at the end of ajax request

Comment: Sorry for not explaining but LITERALLY am  getting Nothing, form submitted without alerting whether sent or not, no thing inserted in DB, No errors!!

Comment: Thanks Alot everyone, but nothing changed!

Comment: @RayanOsman please check once my answer and read comment carefully.

Comment: Use mysqli instead of deprecated mysql functions and also replace value with value() function in req_form.php and change time and date variable name with something else becaue time and date is predefined function. Change your table collation to utf8 family.

Answer (score 0):

value for pure javascript. if you want to get values in jquery, you have to use .val()

```
var des= $("#des").val();
var time= $("#time").val();
var date= $("#date").val();
```

Comment: you missed something which everyone overlooked, but I didn't.

Comment: @Anant I was referring to comment #1 up there ;-) by *moi*.

Comment: @fred-ii form action??

Comment: *lol*  - no, [*this...*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36815877/use-ajax-to-insert-into-databas-without-refreshing-the-page#comment61204347_36815877) @Anant

Comment: @Anant Too many errors in their code and too many unknowns for my cup 'o tea.

Comment: @Anant Well I'm not going to be submitting one. Not without my 20 foot pole ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- great. by the way i need to check it myself. lol. :):)